# How to play mp4 Audio files in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, mp4, avplayer

I have some Audio files in mp4 format - which I used thinking this would be the best format for use on both iOS and Android devices. However they do not play with either AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer. Is there another player that may handle it, or some way (in Swift) to covert them to mp3? Note this only an issue with mp4 audio only files - mp4 videos are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AvPlayer CAN play mp4 files, but not if they are encoded as AMR_NB they need to be encoded as AAC.